# Why my kubernetes pod keep restarting without any error or request?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and I setup master and worker nodes on VMware esxi server with Ubuntu20.0 OS. I deploy postgrads database cluster through master node which are running on node1. They are running successfully but I found that they are restarting very regularly.
This is my yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: postgres
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
---
    kind: PersistentVolume
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: postgres-pv-volume
      labels:
        type: local
        app: postgres
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      capacity:
        storage: 5Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/data"
---
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: postgres-pv-claim
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
    
---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: postgres-config
      labels:
        app: postgres
    data:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: postgres
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
       ports:
        - name: postgres
          port: 5432
          nodePort: 30432
       type: NodePort
       selector:
        app: postgres
```

I also created a storageclass name manual with this yaml file.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp20
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

**What Issue do I face:**
My pods keep restarting even no connecting has been made.
My node port server is not working I am not able to connect database.
The log file last 20 lines are following

```
2022-11-21 09:52:34.737 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-11-21 09:52:34.737 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-11-21 09:52:34.737 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-11-21 09:52:34.739 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-11-21 09:52:34.743 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-21 09:51:09 UTC
2022-11-21 09:52:34.748 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-11-21 09:54:48.522 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-11-21 09:54:48.525 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-11-21 09:54:48.527 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 29) exited with exit code 1
2022-11-21 09:54:48.529 UTC [24] LOG:  shutting down
2022-11-21 09:54:48.531 UTC [24] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2022-11-21 09:54:48.537 UTC [24] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.003 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.008 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2022-11-21 09:54:48.546 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

After 6 restart my PODs show this

```
root@k8smasternode-virtual-machine:/home/k8smasternode# kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS            AGE
postgres-7dff8d6d74-8q9fd   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (<invalid> ago)   22m
```

Comment: This could be almost anything; without seeing any details of the StatefulSet definition it's really hard to say.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], not just diagnostic output?

Comment: David really thanks for your help. I edit the Question. The problem is complex as my Pod hit the crash loop. Please advice me where should I do to find the issue.

Comment: Just to test, I create a nginx! pod on the same setup. It is up and running and I can even access outside . So the issue is with postgres.yaml file. Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: After few min pass the nginx also start restarting and then enter in crashloop.